# How to debug Http 406 ERROR?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, http

We have a "web widget" written in VB or Delphi or something that sends a request (by calling a PHP script) to our webserver (apache) to update the database. It's been working for years until yesterday when the web server returned Error 406: Not Acceptable. We don't know what changed, probably either a windows update to the server hosting our web widget or a change to our shared hosting account on our web server. All we do know is that our webserver now returns 406 because the accept headers in the request header is too strict.

So my question is this:

What can we do to debug this? I think the best I could do right now is log the request header to see what it is by inserting some lines in the PHP script that is called, but it looks like the server returns 406 before even processing the PHP. Help!

Comment: Looks like you need to edit the client to accept _any_ data returned by the web server: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html

Comment: I would use Wireshark.

Comment: @techie007 you know it's never that easy. The guy who wrote it is out of town and we have no permissions to edit or view the source.